# HashMap<Integer,String> how is it taking values <String,Integer>

Tags: java, generics, hashmap

Here is my code, I wonder how is it possible:

```
HashMap<Integer,String> hashmap = new HashMap();
hashmap.put(1,"milind");
hashmap.put(2,"nelay");       

HashMap hash = new HashMap();
hash.put("piyush",1);
hashmap.putAll(hash);
for (Object name: hashmap.keySet()) {
   Object key = name.toString();
   Object value = hashmap.get(name);
   System.out.println(key + " " + value);
}
```

Here is the output:

```
 1 milind
 2 nelay
 piyush 1
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `hashmap` actually did not specify the types for Key/Value, so the Object type *(or sub types including Integer, String and whatsoever)* is acceptable for both key and value.

Here is your first line:

```
HashMap hashmap = new HashMap();
```

If you change this line to:

```
HashMap<Integer, String> hashmap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
```

And continue with the next lines:

```
HashMap hash = new HashMap();
hash.put("piyush", 1);
hashmap.putAll(hash);
```

Then it won't compile.

Comment: After editing the plain markdown, it revealed that the first line was `HashMap<Integer,String> hashmap=new HashMap();`. However, it's interesting why it works with the second, un-parameterized map.

Answer (score 2):

Your HashMaps are not typesafe.
The following will not compile anymore:

```
HashMap<Integer, String> hashmap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    hashmap.put(1, "milind");
    hashmap.put(2, "nelay");

    HashMap<String, Integer> hash = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    hash.put("piyush", 1);
    hashmap.putAll(hash); // will not compile
    for (Object name : hashmap.keySet()) {

        Object key = name.toString();
        Object value = hashmap.get(name);
        System.out.println(key + " " + value);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The generic type parameters, like `<Integer, String>` add some *compile-time* checking. Otherwise, the *HashMap* can contain anything.

Since the second map, `HashMap hash=new HashMap();` has no type parameters, it passes the compiler check for `void putAll(Map<? extends K,? extends V> m)`. Then, it can work well on runtime.

However, the caller of the map will have a **very** difficult task to deal with Objects of unexpected type. This is how you can fix it on compiler level:

```
private static void foo() {
    HashMap<Integer,String> hashmap=new HashMap<>(); // diamond syntax to specify right-hand type
    hashmap.put(1,"milind");
    hashmap.put(2,"nelay");


    HashMap<String, Integer> hash=new HashMap<>(); // diamond syntax again
    hash.put("piyush",1);
    hashmap.putAll(hash);  // compile error
    for (Object name: hashmap.keySet())
   {
        Object key =name.toString();
        Object value = hashmap.get(name);
        System.out.println(key + " " + value);
    }
}
```